# Unity3D Ball not being thrown on swipe

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to throw a basketball using swipe detection.
Depending on the length of the swipe will determine the amount of force applied(Distance ball is thrown.) The GUI Updates, so my swipes are being detected however the basketball does not move at all. I've tried checking kinematic and un-checking it, with the same result. 
The script is attached to my Camera. I dragged the ball object into the object and rigidbody places that were created from the public variables.
Here is the code I'm currently using;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {

    }

    private float length = 0;
    private bool SW = false;
    private Vector3 final;
    private Vector3 startpos;
    private Vector3 endpos;

    public GameObject basketball; //Basketball Obj
    public Rigidbody rbody;// Basketball Obj

    void Update()
    {
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            final = Vector3.zero;
            length = 0;
            SW = false;
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            startpos = new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, 0,             touchDeltaPosition.y);
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            SW = true;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            SW = false;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            SW = false;
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (SW)
            {
                Vector2 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                endpos = new Vector3(touchPosition.x, 0, touchPosition.y);
                final = endpos - startpos;
                length = final.magnitude;
                rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, 0, touchPosition.y));
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(50, 300, 500, 30), "length: " + length);
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't using the length variable in AddForce at all! Did you miss somethin

Comment: This is the first time I've used AddForce, What's the proper syntax? @SurajS

Comment: The syntax is correct! what i meant was you are calculating the value of 'length' but not using it anywhere! perhaps try rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, 0, touchPosition.y)* length);

Comment: Still didn't do anything

Comment: Monitor the localPosition of the ball to see if there are any changes, even if minute, if there are, then you just need to multiply the force with a factor

Comment: Position doesn't change.

Comment: In code? By examining values or visually?

Comment: By tracking the position on start up, and on swipe.
The coordinates are the same.

Comment: rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();   this line takes the basketball objects rb?  If this code is attached to camera , doesn't it will try to take camera's rb ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem, **rbody** references Camera's *rigidbody* (if there is one)

try this code, and ensure that ***basketball*** has a RigidBody component attached!

```
void Update()
    {
        rbody = basketball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            final = Vector3.zero;
            length = 0;
            SW = false;
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            startpos = new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, 0,             touchDeltaPosition.y);
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            SW = true;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            SW = false;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            SW = false;
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (SW)
            {
                Vector2 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                endpos = new Vector3(touchPosition.x, 0, touchPosition.y);
                final = endpos - startpos;
                length = final.magnitude;
                rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.x +touchPosition.y, touchPosition.y));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well this works, sorta. 
Now the ball just vanishes. I assume it's launching too fast. 
I'm using rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, 0, touchPosition.y)); without a multiplying it. 
Tried;
rbody.AddForce(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, 0, touchPosition.y)*100); and the same thing happened.

Comment: Try multiplying with a factor of 0.1f and work your way up

Comment: You could also add a public float Force; in your class and change it from the editor for the ease of it

Comment: Even without multiplying it the ball vanishes, so wouldn't that still cause the same result?

Comment: Multiplying with a factor of 0.1f will just use 10% of the new Vector3, so it is actually decreasing the force applied by 90% when there is no factor.

Comment: Well that worked, the speed seems good but the ball stays on the ground. It doesn't go up in the air with the swipe. It just rolls on the ground.

Comment: That's because the y component of the addForce is 0 I've edited the  code to add that in.

Comment: You can play around with multiplying, adding each of the three scalars in Vector3 until you are satisfied!

Comment: Would that cause the ball to only go towards the right as-well?
If I swipe left it still goes right.

Comment: You have to have a separate if too check if it was swiped left and swiped right, then just negate the x and z components of touch Position accordingly